# XML enumeration - using value with space in it and using multiple selections

Tags: xml, xml-validation

the first question is written above: can I use spaces or not?

```
<xs:simpleType name="Testing">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="my sample spaced value"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="my second spaced value"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="myThirdValue"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="myFourthValue"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

What I've found is  this: [Specify a multi-word enumeration value in an XML/DTD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494690/specify-a-multi-word-enumeration-value-in-an-xml-dtd)

But on the other hand here it says it can be any simple type: http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/e-xsd_enumeration.html

Can I have this question resolved, preferablly with a link to the paragraph in w3c specification?

The second question is how could it validate when I select more than one answer, so the output would be like:

```
<testing>myThirdValue myFourthValue</testing>
```

I'm getting:

> cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'myThirdValue myFourthValue' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[my sample spaced value, my second spaced value, myThirdValue, myFourthValue]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

And how can it not go crazy, when space is used as a separator and I have spaces in value name?

```
<testing>my sample spaced value my second spaced value</testing>
```

Do I have to specify a pattern to be able to parse more than one value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XML DTD != XML Schema (XSD) so the SO question/answer you linked to does not apply to your question.

[According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-enumeration)...

> 4.3.5.5 Constraints on enumeration Schema Components
>
> Schema Component Constraint: enumeration valid restriction
>
> It is an ·error· if any member of {value} is not in the ·value space· of {base
>   type definition}.

So if your base type is `xs:string` (like in your example) then yes the value can contain spaces.

(If I'm reading the spec correctly. Testing appears to support my understanding.)

Other examples...

If your base type is `xs:NMTOKEN`, then no your value cannot contain spaces.

If your base type is `xs:NMTOKENS` (plural), then yes your value can contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I gave some more info in the first post on why it's giving me a headache.

Comment: @Wynarator - You can use `xs:list` to be able to have more than one value, but I don't know how you'd get that to work if your values have spaces.